# Adding/Subtracting values from a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a check box that is by default, is checked and has a value of $50.00. Now I have thought that, what if the user doesn't want to check that $50.00. So, I'm just gonna ask, how will I automatically add it in my grandtotal, and if it is unchecked it will be deducted from grandtotal?

**html**

```
<input type="checkbox" checked value="50.00" id="cbx1" /><label>Upgrade for $50.00</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="10.00" id="cbx2" /><label>Package A</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="20.00" id="cbx3" /><label>Package B</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="30.00" id="cbx4" /><label>Package C</label><br>
<input type="checkbox" value="40.00" id="cbx5" /><label>Package D</label><br>
<input type="text" id="grandtotal"/> Total:
```

**script**

```
function grandtotal(){
            var a = 0;
            var b = 0;
            var c = 0;
            var d = 0;
            var e = 0;

            if ($('#cbx1').is(":checked")) {
                a = parseFloat($("#cbx1").val(), 10);
            }
            if ($('#cbx2').is(":checked")) {
                b = parseFloat($("#cbx2").val(), 10);
            }
            if ($('#cbx3').is(":checked")) {
                c = parseFloat($("#cbx4").val(), 10);
            }
            if ($('#cbx4').is(":checked")) {
               d = parseFloat($("#cbx4").val(), 10);
            }
            if ($('#cbx5').is(":checked")) {
               e = parseFloat($("#cbx5").val(), 10);
            }

            var total =  a + b + c + d + e ;

            $('#grandtotal').val('$' + total.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code, how are you firing grandtotal()? Also, $('#grandtotal').val(total);

Comment: you dont use `parseFloat` with a base figure, that is exclusively for `parseInt`.

Comment: you might be best using a loop: http://pastebin.com/fGj3kLAt Something like that (not ran so syntax might be off)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you can sum it up to this:

```js
//add change event action on checkbox
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
  //change input #grandtotal value according check/uncheck checkboxes
  $("#grandtotal").val(function() {
    //declare a variable to keep the sum of the values
    var sum = 0;
    //using an iterator find and sum the values of checked checkboxes
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      sum += ~~$(this).val();
    });
    return sum;
  });
});

//here change the value according on checked checkboxes on DOM ready event
$("#grandtotal").val(function() {
  var sum = 0;
  $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    sum += ~~$(this).val();
  });
  return sum;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked value="50.00" id="cbx1" />
<label>Upgrade for $50.00</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="10.00" id="cbx2" />
<label>Package A</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="20.00" id="cbx3" />
<label>Package B</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="30.00" id="cbx4" />
<label>Package C</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" value="40.00" id="cbx5" />
<label>Package D</label>
<br>
<input type="text" id="grandtotal" />Total:
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this..**

```
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="grandtotal()" value="50.00" id="cbx1" /><label>Upgrade for $50.00</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="grandtotal()" value="10.00" id="cbx2" /><label>Package A</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="grandtotal()" value="20.00" id="cbx3" /><label>Package B</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="grandtotal()" value="30.00" id="cbx4" /><label>Package C</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="grandtotal()" value="40.00" id="cbx5" /><label>Package D</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="grandtotal"/> Total:




function grandtotal(){
            var a = 0;
            var b = 0;
            var c = 0;
            var d = 0;
            var e = 0;

            if ($('#cbx1').is(":checked")) {
                a = parseFloat($("#cbx1").val(), 10);
            } else {

                a=0;
            }
            if ($('#cbx2').is(":checked")) {
                b = parseFloat($("#cbx2").val(), 10);
            }else {

                b=0;
            }
            if ($('#cbx3').is(":checked")) {
                c = parseFloat($("#cbx4").val(), 10);
            }else {

                c=0;
            }
            if ($('#cbx4').is(":checked")) {
               d = parseFloat($("#cbx4").val(), 10);
            }else {

               d=0;
            }
            if ($('#cbx5').is(":checked")) {
               e = parseFloat($("#cbx5").val(), 10);
            }else {

                e=0;
            }

            var total =  a + b + c + d + e ;

            $('#grandtotal').val('$' + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:I see you now say the text box is checked by default. So just have a onLoad function that calls your total calculations.

then:

Add an onclick attribute to the Checkbox that calls the grandtotal function.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="grandtotal()" value="50.00" id="cbx1" />
```

[See JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s31vg2qg/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:use `onclick`

```js
function grandtotal(){
    var a = 0;

    if ($('#cbx1').is(":checked")) {
        a = parseFloat($("#cbx1").val(), 10);
    }

    var total =  a + 10.00 ;

    $('#grandtotal').val('$' + total.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" value="50.00" id="cbx1" onclick="grandtotal()"/><label>Upgrade for $50.00</label><br>
Total:<input type="text" id="grandtotal" readonly/>
```

Comment: i forgot that it is checked by default, so what I want is the value will be shown in the grandtotal and it will be added with the other values, if the user decides not to check it, the value 50.00 will not be added with the other values.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#cbx1").click(function () {
    if ($('#cbx1').is(":checked")) {
        a = parseFloat($("#cbx1").val(), 10);
        var total =  a + 10.00 ;

    $('#grandtotal').val('$' + total.toFixed(2));
    }
    else{
        $('#grandtotal').val('$'+10);
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox"  value="50.00" id="cbx1" /><label>Upgrade for $50.00</label><br>
<input type="text" id="grandtotal"/> Total:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```js
       $("#cbx1").click(function () {
            var chk = $("#cbx1").val();
            var total = 0;
            if ($("#cbx1").prop("checked") == true) {
                var gtotal = parseInt(total) + parseInt(chk);
    
            } else {
                var gtotal = parseInt(total);
    
            }
            $("#grandtotal").val(gtotal);
        });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/c6gqxL6d/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about simply looping through the checkboxes rather then checking indiviually?

```
    grandTotal () {
        var $packages = $('input:checked'),
            total;

        $packages.each(function(i, package){
             total += $(package).val();
        });

        $('#grandtotal').val('$' + total);
    }
```

Then call grandTotal as and when you need to update the price

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below jsfiddle link,

http://jsfiddle.net/5udtC/7788/

Change the script code as follows,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input").click(function () {
     var a = 0;
        var b = 0;
        var c = 0;
        var d = 0;
        var e = 0;
       if ($('#cbx1').is(":checked")) {
            a = parseFloat($("#cbx1").val(), 10);
        }
        if ($('#cbx2').is(":checked")) {
            b = parseFloat($("#cbx2").val(), 10);
        }
        if ($('#cbx3').is(":checked")) {
            c = parseFloat($("#cbx4").val(), 10);
        }
        if ($('#cbx4').is(":checked")) {
           d = parseFloat($("#cbx4").val(), 10);
        }
        if ($('#cbx5').is(":checked")) {
           e = parseFloat($("#cbx5").val(), 10);
        }
        var total =  a + b + c + d + e ;
        $('#grandtotal').val('$' + total.toFixed(2));
});

 });
```

Hope this helps you..Thank you.